# Power consumed by an LED in a simple circuit

Tags: power, ohms-law

I am in the very beginnings of studying circuits and am a little confused on calculated Power.

If I have a 9V Battery, 4 x 10k Resistors and a single LED, how would I calculate the power consumed by this LED?

I have measured current of the circuit and voltage measured at the LED anode/cathode.

If I am reading my book correctly, is it really as simple as P=V*I?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVkvE0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes, the power consumed by the LED is I*V, where I is the current through the LED and V is the voltage across the LED. How to calculate that for your circuit depends on what the circuit is (hint: there's a button in the question editor that lets you add a schematic to the question).

Comment: Yes, the power consumed by the LED is I*V - but you have to use the right I and V.  If you just want the power consumed by the LED, you use the voltage across the LED.  For the power consumed by the whole circuit, you use the power supply or battery voltage.  The current is the same in either case, for your circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 9V Battery, 4 x 10k Resistors and a single LED, how would I calculate the power consumed by this LED?

You have to know the forward voltage of the LED. A typical number is somewhere between 1.5 and 3 V. Let's say it's 2 V.

Then there is 7 V across the 40 kOhm resistor, so the current flowing is 0.175 mA.

0.175 mA x 2 V is 0.35 mW.

(Note that typically the forward voltage is specified with 5 or 10 or 20 mA flowing. With only 0.2 mA, the actual forward voltage through a real device will be lower, and so the power will be lower. To get a more accurate estimate would require a more detailed model of the LED behavior)

> is it really as simple as P=V*I?

Yes.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation, thank you for taking the time to answer what I am sure to many is a silly and simple question.